# Filter out digits from a CSV File using Java

Tags: java, regex, excel, csv, pattern-matching

I am new to CSV Parsing. I have a CSV file where the 3rd column (a description field) may have one or more 6 digit numbers along with other values. I need to filter out those numbers and write them in the adjacent column corresponding to each row.

Eg:

```
3rd column                       4th column
=============                    ===========
123456adjfghviu77                123456

shgdasd234567                    234567

123456abc:de234567:c567890d      123456-234567-567890

12654352474
```

Please help. This is what I have done so far.

```
        String strFile="D:/Input.csv";
        CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));

        String[] nextline;
        //int lineNumber=0;
        String str="^[\\d|\\s]{5}$";
        String regex="[^\\d]+";

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:/Output.csv");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


        while((nextline=reader.readNext())!=null){
            //lineNumber++;
            //System.out.println("Line : "+lineNumber);
            if(nextline[2].toString().matches(str)){
            pw.print(nextline[1]);
            pw.append('\n');
            System.out.println(nextline[2]);
            }               

        }
        pw.flush();
```

Comment: *may have one or more 6 digit numbers along with other values* -> You have to show us sample input and output

Comment: sorry...updated the question with the sample input.

Comment: The issue is that you are simply checking if the regex pattern _matches_ and then printing the line if it does. You need to use capturing groups and print the _submatches_ instead.

Comment: You forgot to add the appropriate output for the given input.

Comment: _could you please give me an example ?_

Comment: What should be the output, if the 3rd column is '123456adjfghviu77'?

Comment: @Ritesh: http://ideone.com/pzXA3c. Just use `"\\d{6}"`  with `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think this should be posted as an answer (and be accepted).

Comment: @RiteshSatapathy: Have you had a look at my sample code? Is working as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the problem here is not with the string, but with reading one or more strings from a cell in a csv file.

Comment: @RiteshSatapathy you are the one setting the problem, so you should tell us what you want in that case...

Comment: Actually, that is a question to you. See the [updated code example](http://ideone.com/pzXA3c): for  "123456adjfghviu77234567", it will produce `123456`, `772345`.

Comment: @vefthym please see the update qn..

Comment: Try http://ideone.com/1ikOew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you have proposed the best solution. just try to use a StringBuilder in your example.

Comment: @RuudyGarcia: see my answer, but from what I know, string concatenation is ok in Java since under the scenes it uses StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest just matching 6-digit chunks, and build a new string when collecting matches:

```
String s = "123456abc:de234567:c567890d";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)");  // Pattern to match 6 digit chunks not enclosed with digits
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (result.length() == 0)  {              // If the result is empty
        result.append(matcher.group(0));      // add the 6 digit chunk
    } else {
       result.append("-").append(matcher.group(0)); // else add a delimiter and the digits after it
    }
} 
System.out.println(result.toString());      // Demo, use this to write to your new column
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/iaqc9o)

UPDATE: I have changed the pattern from `"\\d{6}"` to `"(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)"` to make sure we only match 6-digit chunks that are *not* enclosed with other digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC0zO3/2)

Comment: thanks for this, however it keeps on appending the values..i need separate outputs for separate rows

Comment: @RiteshSatapathy: Imagine you read a question from a stranger. What should I understand from your comment? *I need to get something  from something else to turn it into something more else*. Please be specific. What are the *criteria* for *matching*? 6-digit chunk that is not enclosed with other digits? Then you need a `"(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)"` regex.

Comment: Also, you need to reset the StringBuilder (just place it in the right place in your code) each time you are reading a new row.

Comment: please I apologize, but if you see the qn, i have updated the the input and output. 3rd column is the input column and 4th column is the output column

Answer (score 1):

All righ, this is what you need to do to get the digits in the third column  :

```
while((nextline=reader.readNext())!=null){
     //For every column (columnNumber)
     String digitsInColumn = nextline[columnNumber].replaceAll("\\D+","");
     // Your treatment 

}
```

Comment: I agree with this..but if that cell has multiple 6 digits values.. i mean something like this `123456hdfhg, sdfg567890`...it will append them together..but i dont want that, i want them separate in another cell

Comment: Well it can't have a comma like in your example, elswhere it won't be the same column. In your explanation. What you said "may have one or more 6 digit numbers along with other values. I need to filter out those numbers and write them in the adjacent column corresponding to each row". digitsInColumn will have the digits in this column, you have to do the same thing for every column to get the digits

Comment: @RiteshSatapathy how would you append the result of 123456adjfghviu77234567 in next column of your output csv file ? Your problem lacks of spec of this usecase

Comment: My bad..the separators are not comma, they are `;` or `:`

Comment: In this case I think that @Wiktor Stribiżew's solution is the one to choose. You have just to loop over the matcher's result using a StringBuilder and add the result to the output csv